# How to change the description of a plane from parametrization to equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I have a doubt regarding ways to describe planes. I know this can be done, via equation and parametrizations. If I have the form of an equation say;

x+3y+z=3, I can turn this into a parametrization making x = 3-3y-z such that the parametrized form is

(3,0,0) + (-3,1,0)y + (-1,0,1)z

My issue is, I don't know how to turn a parametrization back to an equation. Is there any information on the topic, procedure. What is the terminology, I don't know how to properly look for this.

For example: if I give (1,2,1) + (-3,1,3)y + (0,1,2)z , How can I turn this back to a plane expression with only one equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(s,t) = (1,2,1) + (-3,1,3)s + (0,1,2)t$$
I changed $y$ and $z$ to $s$ and $t$ as you can't use $x$ and $y$ as coordinates and as parameters at the same time.

This describes a plane going through the point $P(0,0) = (1,2,1)$ and parallel to the vectors $(-3,1,3)$ and $(0,1,2)$.

Hence the plane is perpendicular to their cross-product
$$(-3,1,3) \times (0,1,2) = (-1,6,-3)$$

So the equation of the plane looks like $-x+6y-3z = c$ for some constant, $c$.

Since the plane passes through the point $(1,2,1)$, its equation is
$$-x+6y-3z = -(1)+6(2)-3(1)$$
$$ -x+6y-3z = 8$$
$$x - 6y + 3z = -8$$

### Verification

$$(x,y,z) = P(s,t) = (1,2,1) + (-3,1,3)s + (0,1,2)t$$
$$(x,y,z) = (1,2,1) + (-3,1,3)s + (0,1,2)t$$
$$(x,y,z) = (1-3s, s+t+2, 3s+2t+1)$$

\begin{align}
   x - 6y + 3z 
   &= (1-3s) - 6(s+t+2) + 3(3s+2t+1) \\
   &= -8
\end{align}

Comment: The answer is more than correct, but it lacks any explanation why

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful